# RMarkdown/Knitr, matching physical figure size and displayed HTML size

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using RMarkdown to create a html file (my preferred format).  I then use the officer package to create a powerpoint (PPT) (everyone else's preferred format) that reads in the .png images that are automatically created and saved when I knit the document (I believe this is default when the fig.path is specified).

To get consistent fontsize throughout the PPT figures, I have specified in each knitr chunk `fig.width, out.width`, etc to be equal to the relevant PPT placeholder dimensions.  E.G if the PPT placeholder is 5.29in high x 5.89in wide, then in the knitr chunk I specify  , `out.height="5.29in", out.width="5.89in", fig.height=5.29, fig.width=5.89`).  This seems to work in terms of the PPT file, however it results in extremely small figures for the HTML file.  Is there a way to get the knitr code to work for both html and PPT, without needing to specifically save the image, using, for example ggsave()?

Following is some auto-generated test code:

````
---
title: "Test_Figure_Size"
output: 
  html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "Delete_Me/", echo=FALSE)
```

When you include out.height, out.width the figure is extremely small in the knitted html document, but perfectly sized as a .png file.
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, out.height="5.29in", out.width="5.89in", fig.height=5.29, fig.width=5.89}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `out.height="5.29in", out.width="5.89in"`, those values are written into the HTML output as `height` and `width` attributes of the `img`.  But `height` and `width` are expressed in pixels, so you'll end up with a figure about 5 pixels square.

I don't use Powerpoint, but is there a way to specify the image size in pixels, e.g. "589px" or something similar?  Then it will use the same scale as the browser, and things should be consistent.

Comment: Powerpoint doesn't take pixels, however,  what you have written helps in conjunction with other internet postings that PPT bases on 96pixels per inch.  So to get a picture scaled correctly in both HTML and PPT I do the following:

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE, out.height="507.84px", out.width="565.44px", fig.height=5.29, fig.width=5.89}
plot(pressure)
```